# How to delete old versions of Adobe CC Applications

Tags: creative-cloud

I have two versions of Adobe AI and PS. My CC dashboard shows everything is "Up to date". How can I get rid of the 2019/old versions properly?

[image: Example of multiple Adobe Applications]

Comment: Why wouldn't you uninstall the unwanted versions via the Creative Cloud app?

Comment: When you installed the new CC20 versions, the installer should give an option to remove older versions - it should also migrate anything in the old app folders at the same time [much simpler now most plugin structures are centralised] though may leave the old app folders in case you have any manually added data in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete old versions of Adobe software, you must do that through the Adobe Creative Cloud application.

1) Open the Adobe Creative Cloud app.

2) Find the version you would like to uninstall and click on the 3 dots on the bottom right, and then Uninstall.

[image: Uninstall example]